# BufferedImage TYPE_BYTE_BINARY change color of pixel

Tags: java, image

I have been struggling to find and answer to this issue. I am trying to change the color of a pixel in a large BufferedImage with the imageType of TYPE_BYTE_BINARY. By default when I create the image it will create a black image which is fine but I cannot seem to be able to change pixel color to white.

This is the basic idea of what I want to do.

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(dim[0], dim[1], BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
bi.setRBG(x, y, 255)
```

This seems weird to me as a TYPE_BYTE_BINARY image will not have RGB color, so I know that that is not the correct solution.

Another idea that I had was to create multiple bufferedImage TYPE_BYTE_BINARY with the createGraphics() method and then combine all of those buffered images into one large bufferedImage but I could not find any information about that when using the TYPE_BYTE_BINARY imageType.

When reading up on this I came across people saying that you need to use createGraphics() method on the BufferedImage but I don't want to do that as it will use up too much memory.

I came across this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html specifically for this method createPackedRaster()(the second one). This seems like it might be on the right track.

Are those the only options to be able to edit a TYPE_BYTE_BINARY image? Or is there another way that is similar to the way that python handles 1 bit depth images?

In python this is all that needs to be done.

```
im = Image.new("1", (imageDim, imageDim), "white")
picture = im.load()
picture[x, y] = 0 # 0 or 1 to change color black or white
```

All help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All works. I am able to get a white pixel on the image.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;

public class MakeImage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        im.setRGB(10, 10, Color.WHITE.getRGB());

        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(im, "png", new File("image.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Some exception occured " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that is a simple solution, I have been struggling for so long. Thanks Marius!

Comment: For me it is too a stuningly simple solution showing that it can be short in Java too :). You are welcome!